# Python video errors?

Tags: python, pygame

I don't understand why it's not running please someone help me out.

I have downloaded pygame libraries already

```
import pygame

FPS = 60

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
movie = pygame.movie.Movie("/Users/admin/Desktop/Starlite.mpg")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(movie.get_size())
movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()

movie.set_display(movie_screen)
movie.play()


playing = True
while playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            movie.stop()
            playing = False

    screen.blit(movie_screen,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

here is the error message i get in the terminal.

```
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
2019-01-28 13:56:12.273 Python[44653:4791526] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to (null)
vidtest.py:7: RuntimeWarning: use movie: None
  movie = pygame.movie.Movie("/Users/admin/Desktop/Starlite.mpg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vidtest.py", line 7, in <module>
    movie = pygame.movie.Movie("/Users/admin/Desktop/Starlite.mpg")
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 108, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
NotImplementedError: movie module not available
```

Comment: Try: `movie = pygame.movie.Movie(r'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Starlite.mpg')`

Comment: What pygame version is this?

Comment: The `movie` submodule for pygames has been deprecated; while the module still exists, there's no actual implementation for playing videos.

Comment: its pygame 1.9.4 . i believe

Comment: So Matthew Trevor how would import it to play my video